# Call attribute method python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to display hour when i call `date.now.hour` but I get this error

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'hour'
```

this is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class Date:
    def now(self):
        self.hour = "hour"
        print "Now"
    
    def __call__(self, string):
        print string    
    
date = Date()
date('hello') # print hello
date.now.hour # print hour
```

My task is

> Make a class that can do this:
>
> `date.now()` - output: `'now'`
>
> `date('hai')` - output: `'hai'`
>
> `date.now` output: `'now'`
>
> `date.now.hour` output: `'hour'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are quite close - one of your tasks are already done:

> `date('hai')` - `output: 'hai'`

What is still left to do is

> `date.now()` - output: `'now'`
>
> `date.now` - output: `'now'`
>
> `date.now.hour` output: `'hour'`

So your `date.now` has quite a lot of requirements which only can be accomplished with a separate class:

```
class Now(object):
    def __str__(self): return ...
    def __call__(self): return ...
    hour = property(lambda self: 'hour')
```

or something like this.

This class you can use inside your `class Date`.

---

Another option would be to have `now` be a property of your `class Date`, but this would work analogous. You'd need a `class Now` like above, but you would it use like

```
class Date(object):
    def __call__ # as before
    @property
    def now(self):
        return Now()
```

Comment: so I have to use two class?

Answer (score 5):

Just call it `date.now()` - you'll never be able to access the `hour` attribute of the function since it's an attribute of the object.

Doing `date.hour` will allow you to see `hour`.

```
>>> date.hour
'hour'
```

What you should do though is set all of these properties in the `__init__` function of your class.

```
class Date():
    def __init__(self, hour):
        self.hour = hour

    def now(self):
       print self.hour #if you will

    def __call__(self string):
       print string
```

Comment: I have a task. Make a class that can do this:
<pre><code>
date.now()
output: 'now'

date('hai')
output: 'hai'

date.now
output: 'now'

date.now.hour
output: 'hour'

</code></pre>

Comment: This syntax, where you call an argument-less function without the ()'s is something you do in Ruby or VB - it's not done in Python unless you set up the function as a property - in which case `date.now()` would fail, since the returned string value is not callable.

Answer (score 2):

The `now` function is setting the attribute `hour` on your class. If you do the following you should see the hour printed:

```
date = Date()
date.now()
date.hour
```

Answer (score 2):

`now` is a method on `Date` class, `hour` is an attribute:

```
date = Date()
date('hello') # print hello
date.now() # print Now
print date.hour # print hour
```

Answer (score 1):

`date.hour` is the right approach. You assign hour to the object (`self`), not to the function.

However, initializing instance attributes in methods is error-prone and a bad habit. You should redefine an `__init__` method like this:

```
class Date:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hour = 'hour'
```

Comment: I have a task, to print 'hour' string when I call date.now.hour

Comment: It doesn't make sense. Can you post the task like you got it, not like you're interpreting it? It seems to me like some kind of misunderstanding. (You can't 'call' strings)

Comment: make a class that can do this:

date.now()
output: 'now'

date('hai')
output: 'hai'

date.now
output: 'now'

date.now.hour
output: 'hour'

Comment: Do what? Post the __full__ task you got, not fragments of it, word for word.

Comment: Well, it is clear that if date.now would be a string, you couldn't neither access nor define date.now.hour (strings are not mutable). That means date.now must be a user defined class.